# How do frameworks update the DOM without a virtual DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, ember.js, knockout.js

I have been researching React's virtual DOM (how it works) for a while now, and so far I have understood the following:

- It has an in-memory DOM representation at all times
- When something changes in the application/component, the virtual DOM creates another representation of component's/application's DOM - this time how it should look like
- It "diffs" them to find the minimum differences that need to be updated in the real DOM
- It updates the real DOM

I wanted to know if other frameworks update DOM and detect changes differently and if they do - how?

Comment: I removed backbone as it doesn't render on it's own, it's just jQuery by default, and how it renders is left to implement by the developer.

Comment: Also, this looks too broad to ask on Stack Overflow and it is likely to be [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). See the help for [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "one answer" to your question (so it might be too broad in that sense...), but it might be answerable for the individual frameworks you've tagged.

---

### For knockout:

**Dependency tracking**

Knockout lets you put values inside `observable` instances. An `observable` value lets you `subscribe` to changes. I.e.:

```
const myValue = ko.observable(0);
myValue.subscribe( newValue => console.log(newValue) );

// Set:
myValue(1); // Logs 1

// Get:
myValue(); // Returns 1
```

**Binding handlers**

The way knockout updates the DOM is via binding handlers. A binding handler defines how a *changed observable influences the DOM*. Let's think of a fictive, heavily simplified way to update the `value` attribute for an element:

```
const bindValue = (element, obs) => obs.subcribe(
  newValue => element.value = newValue
);

// Sync the value of our observable `myValue` to an
// `<input>`s value attribute:
bindValue(document.querySelector("input"), myValue);
```

**Binding your views**

You won't see code like this in a real knockout project, because knockout wants you to define these relations within your "views" (HTML), via the `data-bind` attribute:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myObs" />
```

And activate by:

```
ko.applyBindings({ myObs: myObs });
```

**Concluding**

So, rather than keeping track of a virtual DOM, knockout implements a dependency tracking/subscription system and defines handler methods to update DOM elements in `data-binds`.

There are several strategies implemented that help you prevent performance issues. For example:

- `subscription` triggers can be rate limited, throttled and deferred to tasks.
- Rendered DOM elements can be cached and re-used when moved across the DOM